# Which version of Java should I download?

Tags: java

I'm using a laptop that runs 64-bit Windows 7. Unfortunately, I uninstalled Java from my computer, and I don't know which version I was using. Please help me determine which version of Java I should install.

Comment: I would download the latest supported version from Oracle Java 6 update 23.

Answer (score 3):

I would read this [link](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml). The correct download for JAVA is dependent on what browser you are using.  If you are using a 32 bit browser, even though you are on a 64 bit machine, you will need the 32 bit version of Java. And obviously, if you are using a 64 bit version of your browser, you will need the 64 bit Java.

Answer (score 1):

As Dabeer said, depending on the browser, but if you are running Java applications you may receive better performance running in the native 'bit' version. As far as I know, Internet Explorer x64 comes with a fresh install of Windows x64, and thus far I haven't seen an up to date 64 bit version of Firefox or Chrome.

I downloaded both the Java SDK x64 and the Java plugin x86 and they both run perfect side by side. My rationale between getting the 64 bit SDK is due to my thought that Minecraft would run better, and so far it has. If you are not running standalone Java applications (such as Minecraft in my instance) and wanting to improve performance you can use the same version you run in the browser.

Comment: I believe Windows 7 64, comes with the ability to run IE in both forms 32 and 64.  It may just be as simple as launching the exe from the Program Files and Program Files (x86) directories.

Comment: For Firefox, the current official nightly builds do have x64 builds available for Windows.  I haven't tested them, nor do I know at what point they'll be released widely.  As of 4.0b11, there's not an "official" x64 build available from the website.

Comment: @afrazier , thanks for the heads up about the nightly build, I'll have to look into them. Do you know if plugins I already have will still work?

Comment: 32-bit plugins won't work with 64-bit Firefox.  It's the same problem that 64-bit IE, Office, etc. all have.  Most extensions should work, since many of them are JS+HTML+CSS.  A few do have dll components (e.g. Gesso, probably IE Tab) though and won't work.